# SQLITE strftime() function issue

Tags: sql, sqlite, date, strftime

```
SELECT strftime('%W', 'Week'), sum(income) FROM tableOne GROUP BY Week;
```

Format for date is a simple date: YYYY-MM-DD

PROBLEM: When run no value for the Week column is provided.  Any suggestions?

There is data in the table and when the query is run the income is summarized by the date in the week column.  Thing is, this column contains a date that may be any day of the week and often multiple different days of the same week.  I need to summarize the income by week.

Comment: Do you have data on your table? hehe

Comment: post your query execution output

Comment: The second parameter in the `strftime()` function needs to be `timestring`. Literal `'Week'` is not a valid format. See [docs](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: Sorry, not currently near my computer, but to be clear, 'Week' is a column in the table with a format of YYYY-MM-DD.  All I really need is to pull what the week number is for that year for a given date in the 'Week' column.

Comment: Couldn't get the return key on the mobile version of this website to enter a new line rather than post the reply, but horizontally the output is something like this: week 2016-05-03  income 4753.   Week 2016-05-05 income 4636.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, `'Week'` is a string containing four characters.
To reference the value in a column named "Week", remove the quotes: `Week`.

Comment: Thanks CL!  I knew it would be something I was over looking!